# Падает сайт на VPS Как найти проблему?

Tags: сервер, vps, vds

Здравствуйте. Есть сайт на Joomla все это дело сидит на VPS. И постоянно в одно и тоже время сайт на этой Joomla падает,  открывается через раз. Как найти в чем проблема. В самом СМS или в сервере. Чем и как протестировать?

Comment: Если время перебоев всегда одно и тоже, то возможно на сервере запускается какой-то процесс. Посмотрите в crontab и cron. Посмотрите в логах.

Comment: ок, гляну. Спасибо за помощь. Ато я в этом деле новичук и незнаю пока куда рить.

Comment: а какой VPS вы используете?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman VDS стоит centos-6-i386 + ispmanager
CPU 1240Mhz, 880Mb memory  Все это здесь - my.core-vps.lv

Comment: @MikhailVaysman нашел в логах в кроне в файле secure такую много кратную запись, причем как раз в то время когда сайт падал. Это что попытка взлома?
Failed password for root from 178.164.238.155 port 1279 ssh2

Comment: Я думаю, что с этим вопросом следует обратиться в службу поддержки.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman куча таких запросов, причем по разным портам. Я так понял питаются сбрутить пароль. Но разве это может так напрягать сервер с посещаемостью 300 человек в сутки?

Comment: это может повесить сам сервер, смотря как брутить пароль.